# Laravel- How to cache custom query with Redis

Tags: laravel, caching, eloquent, redis

How can I cache custom query into redis. I am trying the following

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->orders_sql = Cache::remember('orders', 10, function () {
        return $query = DB::connection('db1')->table('orders as o')
            ->leftJoin('addresses as pa', 'o.id', '=', 'pa.order_id')
            ->leftJoin('users as u', 'o.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
            ->leftJoin('clients', 'clients.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
            ->select(
                'o.id as id', 'o.type as type', 'o.extra_info as extra_info', 'o.status as order_status', 'o.created_at as created_at', 'o.type as order_type', 'o.inspection_date as inspection_date', 'o.assignee as assignee', 'o.user_id as user_id', 'o.inspector_name as inspector_name',
                'pa.address as address', 'pa.city as city', 'pa.state as state',
                'clients.first_name as first_name', 'clients.middle_name as middle_name', 'clients.last_name as last_name'
            )
            ->whereIn('o.status', OrderHelper::$ALLOWED_STATUS)
            ->where('o.type', '<>', OrderHelper::$CONSTRUCTION_EXISTING)
            ->where('o.deleted_at', null);
    });
}
public function orders($sort_by, $sort_order, $limit, $filters)
    {
        if ($filters) {
            $query = $this->applyFilters($filters);
        }
        $orders = $query->orderBy($sort_by ?? OrderHelper::$DEFAULT_SORT_COLUMN, $sort_order ?? OrderHelper::$DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
        if ($limit === 'all') {
            $orders = $orders->get();
        } else {
            $orders = $orders->get();
//            $orders = $orders->paginate($limit ?? CommonHelper::$DEFAULT_PAGINATION_LIMIT);
        }
        //adding more information with orders such as Bank and address info
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $order->created_at = OrderHelper::getFormattedDate($order->id);
            $order->draw = OrderHelper::draw($order->id);
            $order->inspection_date = OrderHelper::getFormattedInspectionDate($order->inspection_date);
            $order->client_name = $order->first_name . ' ' . $order->middle_name . ' ' . $order->last_name;
            $order->type = OrderHelper::getFormattedOrderType($order);
            if (empty($order->assignee)) {
                $order->inspector_name = '-';
            }
        }
        return $orders ? $orders : false;
    }
```

And I am getting the error as

```
"message": "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed",
    "exception": "Exception",
    "file": "/var/www/api.local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisStore.php",
    "line": 295,
```

Comment: This is useless. U'r caching the query, however, after getting query from redis, it still need to run in DB for getting the results. And, database has already cached the query for the next request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are using one of the laravel services like queue or something if yes in your case laravel tries uses [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function to serialize the class properties but one problem with `serialize()` function is that it cannot serialize closure that you are passing
**anonymous functions cannot be serialized** thats php behavior

What you can do is to try to assign the result to the property or pass the result to the constructor...

Comment: I need to stop the calls to DB. This way I will still be sending calls to DB